# ERROR Error: ENOENT: no such file or directory, open when create a text file in node js

Tags: javascript, node.js, docker, filesystems

I'm new to node js please help me to solve this. 
I want to create a text file in node js. I'm using following code segment for that.

```
    var d = new Date();
    var filename = '../upload/' + d.getFullYear() + '-' + pad((d.getMonth() + 1).toString()) + '-' + pad((d.getDate()).toString()) + '.txt';
    if (currentlogstreamfilename != filename) {
        currentlogstreamfilename = filename;
        console.log("Path: " + currentlogstreamfilename);
        currentlogstream = fs.createWriteStream(currentlogstreamfilename, { flags: 'a' });
    }
```

locally this is working perfectly. But inside the docker I'm getting.

ERROR Error: ENOENT: no such file or directory, open '../upload/2018-11-07.txt'

Any solution for this..

Comment: what kind of a setup you have in your Dockerfile ?

Comment: I'm using 
Operating System: Ubuntu 18.04.1 LTS
OSType: linux
Architecture: x86_64

Comment: `FROM alpine:3.7

# Update
RUN apk add --update nodejs 

# Bundle app source
COPY . /app

# Install app dependencies
RUN cd /app; npm install

EXPOSE  3005
CMD ["node", "/app/app.js"]`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Thanks for all. I used node path as following. It worked fine.

```
var path = require('path');
var filename = path.join(__dirname,'../upload/' + d.getFullYear() + '-' + pad((d.getMonth() + 1).toString()) + '-' + pad((d.getDate()).toString()) + '.txt');
```

Answer (score 0):

don't use relative path name such `../`. use an absolute path in your application. you can say

```
filename = __dirname + '/upload + d.getYear() + ...
```

or if you want to save this file in the parent directory you should first get running process root path. which you can say:

```
filename = process.cwd() + 'uploads/' + d.getYear() + ...
```

Comment: thanks @amir
I confused with the folder structure. This js file is in another directory. `../` used for go to previous directory.